# Send command to background while capturing stdin/stdout using bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a command to start `livy-server` that works on the command line directly:

```
$cd /git/livy; nohup bin/livy-server > /tmp/livy.log 2>&1 &
[1] 4370
19:11:11/livy $
19:11:12/livy $ll /tmp/livy.log
-rw-r--r--  1 boes  wheel  436 Jan 26 19:11 /tmp/livy.log
```

But it does *not* from a function.  In my `~/.profile` there is a function to start `livy-server`:

```
startlivy() { cd /git/livy; nohup bin/livy-server > /tmp/livy.log 2>&1 & ; }

/Users/boescst/.profile: line 432: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
-bash: /Users/boes/.profile: line 432: `startlivy() { cd /git/livy; nohup bin/livy-server > /tmp/livy.log 2>&1 & ; }'
```

Do the `&` ampersands need to be escaped somehow?

BTW although this probably does not affect the result - I am on `El Capitan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the final semicolon which needs to be removed.

> startlivy() { cd /git/livy; nohup bin/livy-server > /tmp/livy.log 2>&1
>   & }

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue only occurs when attempting to use a one-liner: i.e the following *does* work:

```
startlivy() { 
     cd /git/livy
      nohup bin/livy-server > /tmp/livy.log 2>&1 &  
}
```

Note: if anyone knows how to handle this in a one liner I'd like to know - and will award .

Comment: Remove the last semicolon in your original one-liner and try again.

Comment: @n8te  Go ahead and make an answer - hey 25 points 4 u.